# How to write literal for Tab key to use for motion?

Tags: cursor-motions, normal-mode, ex-mode, tab-characters

I've the following dummy file created via:

```
echo -e "a a\tb b\tc c" > file
```

Is there any literal for space which I can use for motion argument?

For example this works (which removes the 1st `a a` column):

```
ex +'%norm df ' -sc'%p|q!' file
```

but only when the whitespace was typed manually by <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>.

I've tried already: `\t`, `<Tab>`, `<c-v><Tab>`, etc., but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
vim -c':exe ":%norm df\<Tab>"' -c ':wq' file
```

(not sure, why you are using -sc '%p' thing)

The `:exe "norm <key>"` is documented at `:h expr-quote`

Comment: The `-sc'%p|q!'` is to print to the standard output and quit (without saving in-place), just an alternative way for input parsing like `sed`/`awk`.

Comment: Why `:exe` is required?

Comment: to parse the `"\<key>"` string

Comment: Linked to your example from here: [Deleting first column with vim](http://askubuntu.com/a/686268/78223). Basically I wanted to find simple `ex` cmd removing first column.